# How do I fix a problem to call a function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, require

I'm trying to use some ruby code that I've found in Github. I've downloaded the code and did the necessary imports the "requires" and tried to run it as it is described in the readme file on github repository. The code is the following:

In the file `pcset_test.rb` the code is the following:

```
require './pcset.rb'
require 'test/unit'

#
# When possible, test cases are adapted from 
# Introduction to Post-Tonal Theory by Joseph N. Straus,
# unless obvious or otherwise noted.
#

class PCSetTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_init
    #assert_raise(ArgumentError) {PCSet.new []}
    assert_raise(ArgumentError) {PCSet.new [1, 2, 3, 'string']}
    assert_raise(ArgumentError) {PCSet.new "string"}
    assert_raise(ArgumentError) {PCSet.new [1, 2, 3.6, 4]}
    assert_equal([0, 1, 2, 9], PCSet.new([0, 1, 2, 33, 13]).pitches)
    assert_equal([3, 2, 1, 11, 10, 0], PCSet.new_from_string('321bac').pitches)
    assert_equal([0,2,4,5,7,11,9], PCSet.new([12,2,4,5,7,11,9]).pitches)
    assert_nothing_raised() {PCSet.new []}
  end

  def test_inversion

  end

  def test_transposition

  end

  def test_multiplication

  end

  #
  # set                   normal                 prime                 forte #
  # 0,2,4,7,8,11          7,8,11,0,2,4           0,1,4,5,7,9           6-31
  # 0,1,2,4,5,7,11        11,0,1,2,4,5,7         0,1,2,3,5,6,8         7-Z36
  # 0,1,3,5,6,7,9,10,11   5,6,7,9,10,11,0,1,3    0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10    9-8
  #

  def test_normal_form
    testPC = PCSet.new [0,4,8,9,11]
    assert_kind_of(PCSet, testPC.normal_form)
    assert_equal([8,9,11,0,4], testPC.normal_form.pitches)
    assert_equal([10,1,4,6], PCSet.new([1,6,4,10]).normal_form.pitches)
    assert_equal([2,4,8,10], PCSet.new([10,8,4,2]).normal_form.pitches)
    assert_equal([7,8,11,0,2,4], PCSet.new([0,2,4,7,8,11]).normal_form.pitches)
    assert_equal([11,0,1,2,4,5,7], PCSet.new([0,1,2,4,5,7,11]).normal_form.pitches)
    assert_equal([5,6,7,9,10,11,0,1,3], PCSet.new([0,1,3,5,6,7,9,10,11]).normal_form.pitches)  
  end

  def test_prime_form
    assert_equal([0,1,2,6], PCSet.new([5,6,1,7]).prime.pitches)
    assert_equal([0,1,4], PCSet.new([2,5,6]).prime.pitches)
    assert_equal([0,1,4,5,7,9], PCSet.new([0,2,4,7,8,11]).prime.pitches)
    assert_equal([0,1,2,3,5,6,8], PCSet.new([0,1,2,4,5,7,11]).prime.pitches)
    assert_equal([0,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10], PCSet.new([0,1,3,5,6,7,9,10,11]).prime.pitches)
  end

  def test_set_class
    testPcs = PCSet.new([2,5,6])
    testPrime = testPcs.prime
    assert_equal([
        [2,5,6], [3,6,7], [4,7,8], [5,8,9], [6,9,10], [7,10,11],
        [8,11,0],[9,0,1], [10,1,2],[11,2,3],[0,3,4],  [1,4,5],
        [6,7,10],[7,8,11],[8,9,0], [9,10,1],[10,11,2],[11,0,3],
        [0,1,4], [1,2,5], [2,3,6], [3,4,7], [4,5,8],  [5,6,9]
      ].sort, PCSet.new([2,5,6]).set_class.map{|x| x.pitches})
    assert_equal(testPcs.set_class.map{|x| x.pitches}, testPrime.set_class.map{|x| x.pitches})
  end

  def test_interval_vector
    assert_equal([2,1,2,1,0,0], PCSet.new([0,1,3,4]).interval_vector)
    assert_equal([2,5,4,3,6,1], PCSet.new([0,1,3,5,6,8,10]).interval_vector)
    assert_equal([0,6,0,6,0,3], PCSet.new([0,2,4,6,8,10]).interval_vector)
  end

  def test_complement
    assert_equal([6,7,8,9,10,11], PCSet.new([0,1,2,3,4,5]).complement.pitches)
    assert_equal([3,4,5], PCSet.new([0,1,2], 6).complement.pitches)
  end

  #
  # Test values from (Morris 1991), pages 105-111
  # Citation:
  # Morris. Class Notes for Atonal Music Theory
  # Lebanon, NH. Frog Peak Music, 1991.
  #
  def test_invariance_vector
    assert_equal([1,0,0,0,5,6,5,5],PCSet.new([0,2,5]).invariance_vector)
    assert_equal([2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6],PCSet.new([0,1,6,7]).invariance_vector)
    assert_equal([6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6],PCSet.new([0,2,4,6,8,10]).invariance_vector)
    assert_equal([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],PCSet.new([0,1,2,3,4,5,8]).invariance_vector)
    assert_equal([1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],PCSet.new([0,1,2,3,5,6,8]).invariance_vector)
    assert_equal([12,12,12,12,0,0,0,0],PCSet.new([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]).invariance_vector)
  end

  #
  # Test values from (Huron 1994). Huron rounds, thus the 0.01 margin of error.
  # Citation:
  # Huron. Interval-Class Content in Equally Tempered Pitch-Class Sets: 
  # Common Scales Exhibit Optimum Tonal Consonance. 
  # Music Perception (1994) vol. 11 (3) pp. 289-305
  #
  def test_huron
    h1 = PCSet.new([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]).huron
    assert_in_delta(-0.2, h1[0], 0.01)
    assert_in_delta(0.21, h1[1], 0.01)
    h2 = PCSet.new([0,2,4,5,7,9,11]).huron
    assert_in_delta(4.76, h2[0], 0.01)
    assert_in_delta(0.62, h2[1], 0.01)
  end

  def test_coherence

  end
end
```

And in the file `pcset.rb` the folloing code:

```
#
# => PCSet Class for Ruby
# => Beau Sievers
# => Hanover, Fall 2008.
#
#
# TODO: Make this a module to avoid namespace collisions.
#       Lilypond and MusicXML output
#

include Math

def choose(n, k)
  return [[]] if n.nil? || n.empty? && k == 0
  return [] if n.nil? || n.empty? && k > 0
  return [[]] if n.size > 0 && k == 0
  c2 = n.clone
  c2.pop
  new_element = n.clone.pop
  choose(c2, k) + append_all(choose(c2, k-1), new_element)
end

def append_all(lists, element)
  lists.map { |l| l << element }
end

def array_to_binary(array)
  array.inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + 2**n}
end

# the following method is horrifically inelegant 
# but avoids monkey-patching.
# TODO: do this right, incl. error checking
def pearsons(x, y)
  if !x.is_a?(Array) || !y.is_a?(Array) then raise StandardError, "x and y must be arrays", caller end
  if x.size != y.size then raise StandardError, "x and y must be same size", caller end
  sum_x = x.inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + n}
  sum_y = y.inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + n}
  sum_square_x = x.inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + n * n}
  sum_square_y = y.inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + n * n}
  xy = []
  x.zip(y) {|a, b| xy.push(a * b)}
  sum_xy = xy.inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + n}
  num = sum_xy - ((sum_x * sum_y)/x.size)
  den = Math.sqrt((sum_square_x - ((sum_x*sum_x)/x.size)) * (sum_square_y - ((sum_y*sum_y)/x.size)))
  (num/den)
end

class PCSet
  include Comparable
  attr_reader :pitches, :base, :input

  def initialize(pcarray, base = 12)
    if pcarray.instance_of?(Array) && pcarray.all?{|pc| pc.instance_of?(Fixnum)}
      @base, @input = base, pcarray
      @pitches = pcarray.map{ |x| x % @base }.uniq
    else
      raise ArgumentError, "Improperly formatted PC array", caller
    end
  end

  def PCSet.new_from_string(pcstring, base = 12)
    if base > 36 then raise StandardError, "Use PCSet.new to create pcsets with a base larger than 36", caller end
    pcarray = []
    pcstring.downcase.split(//).each do |c|
      if c <= 'z' and c >= '0' then pcarray.push(c.to_i(36)) end
    end
    PCSet.new pcarray, base
  end

  def <=>(pcs)
    @pitches <=> pcs.pitches
  end

  def [](index)
    @pitches[index]
  end

  # Intersection
  def &(other)
    PCSet.new @pitches & other.pitches
  end

  # Union
  def |(other)
    PCSet.new @pitches | other.pitches
  end

  def inspect
    @pitches.inspect
  end

  def length  
    @pitches.length
  end

  def invert(axis = 0)
    PCSet.new @pitches.map {|x| (axis-x) % @base}
  end

  def invert!(axis = 0)
    @pitches.map! {|x| (axis-x) % @base}
  end

  def transpose(interval)
    PCSet.new @pitches.map {|x| (x + interval) % @base}
  end

  def transpose!(interval)
    @pitches.map! {|x| (x + interval) % @base}
  end

  def multiply(m = 5)
    PCSet.new @pitches.map {|x| (x * m) % @base}
  end

  def multiply!(m = 5)
    @pitches.map! {|x| (x * m) % @base}
  end

  def zero
    transpose(-1 * @pitches[0])
  end

  def zero!
    transpose!(-1 * @pitches[0])
  end

  def transpositions
    (0..(@base-1)).to_a.map{|x| @pitches.map {|y| (y + x) % @base}}.sort.map {|x| PCSet.new x}
  end

  def transpositions_and_inversions(axis = 0)
    transpositions + invert(axis).transpositions
  end

  #
  # Normal form after Straus. Morris and AthenaCL do this differently.
  #
  def normal_form
    tempar = @pitches.sort
    arar = []                 # [[1,4,7,8,10],[4,7,8,10,1], etc.] get each cyclic variation
    tempar.each {arar.push PCSet.new(tempar.unshift(tempar.pop))}
    most_left_compact(arar)
  end

  def normal_form!
    @pitches = normal_form.pitches
  end

  def is_normal_form?
    self.pitches == self.normal_form.pitches
  end

  def set_class
    transpositions_and_inversions.map{|pcs| pcs.normal_form}.sort
  end

  def prime
    most_left_compact([normal_form.zero, invert.normal_form.zero])
  end

  def prime!
    self.pitches = self.prime.pitches
  end

  def is_prime?
    self.pitches == self.prime.pitches
  end

  def complement
    new_pitches = []
    @base.times do |p|
      if !@pitches.include? p then
        new_pitches.push p
      end
    end
    PCSet.new new_pitches
  end

  def full_interval_vector
    pairs = choose(@pitches, 2)                       # choose every pc pair
    intervals = pairs.map {|x| (x[1] - x[0]) % @base} # calculate every interval
    i_vector = Array.new(@base-1).fill(0)
    intervals.each {|x| i_vector[x-1] += 1}            # count the intervals
    i_vector
  end

  def interval_vector
    i_vector = full_interval_vector
    (0..((@base-1)/2)-1).each {|x| i_vector[x] += i_vector.pop}
    i_vector
  end

  #
  # Morris's invariance vector
  #
  def invariance_vector(m = 5)
    t = transpositions.map!{|pcs| self & pcs}
    ti = invert.transpositions.map!{|pcs| self & pcs}    
    tm = multiply(m).transpositions.map!{|pcs| self & pcs}   
    tmi = invert.multiply(m).transpositions.map!{|pcs| self & pcs}   
    tc = complement.transpositions.map!{|pcs| self & pcs}   
    tic = complement.invert.transpositions.map!{|pcs| self & pcs}
    tmc = complement.multiply(m).transpositions.map!{|pcs| self & pcs}
    tmic = complement.invert.multiply(m).transpositions.map!{|pcs| self & pcs}

    [t, ti, tm, tmi, tc, tic, tmc, tmic].map{|x| x.reject{|pcs| pcs.pitches != @pitches}.length}
  end

  # Huron's aggregate dyadic consonance measure. 
  # Huron. Interval-Class Content in Equally Tempered Pitch-Class Sets: 
  # Common Scales Exhibit Optimum Tonal Consonance. 
  # Music Perception (1994) vol. 11 (3) pp. 289-305
  def huron
    if @base != 12 then raise StandardError, "PCSet.huron only makes sense for mod 12 pcsets", caller end

    #              m2/M7   M2/m7  m3/M6  M3/m6  P4/P5   A4/d5
    huron_table = [-1.428, -0.582, 0.594, 0.386, 1.240, -0.453]
    interval_consonance = []
    interval_vector.zip(huron_table) {|x, y| interval_consonance.push(x * y) }
    aggregate_dyadic_consonance = interval_consonance.inject {|sum, n| sum + n}
    [aggregate_dyadic_consonance, pearsons(interval_vector, huron_table)]
  end

  #
  # Balzano's vector of relations. Citation for all Balzano methods:
  # 
  # Balzano. "The Pitch Set as a Level of Description for Studying Musical
  # Pitch Perception" in Music, Mind, and Brain ed. Clynes. Plenum Press. 1982.
  #
  def vector_of_relations
    (0..length-1).to_a.map do |i|
      (0..length-1).to_a.map do |j|
        (@pitches[(i + j) % length] - @pitches[i]) % @base
      end
    end
  end

  #
  # Checks if the set satisfies Balzano's uniqueness.
  #
  def is_unique?
    vector_of_relations.uniq.size == vector_of_relations.size
  end

  #
  # Checks if the set satisfies Balzano's scalestep-semitone coherence.
  # For all s[i] and s[i1]:
  # j < k => v[i][j] < v[i1][k]
  # Where j and k are scalestep-counting indices.
  # And unless v[i][j] == 6 (a tritone), in which case the strict inequality is relaxed.
  #
  def is_coherent?
    v = vector_of_relations
    truth_array = []
    all_pair_indices = choose((0..length-1).to_a, 2)
    all_pair_indices.each do |i, i1|
      all_pair_indices.each do |j, k|
        if v[i][j] == 6
          truth_array.push(v[i][j] <= v[i1][k])
        else
          truth_array.push(v[i][j] < v[i1][k])    
        end
        if v[i1][j] == 6
          truth_array.push(v[i1][j] <= v[i][k])
        else
          truth_array.push(v[i1][j] < v[i][k])
        end
      end
    end
    !truth_array.include?(false)
  end

  #
  # Strict Balzano coherence, no inequality relaxation for tritones.
  #
  def is_strictly_coherent?
    v = vector_of_relations
    truth_array = []
    all_pair_indices = choose((0..length-1).to_a, 2)
    all_pair_indices.each do |i, i1|
      all_pair_indices.each do |j, k|
        truth_array.push(v[i][j] < v[i1][k])
        truth_array.push(v[i1][j] < v[i][k])
      end
    end
    !truth_array.include?(false)
  end

  def notes(middle_c = 0)
    noteArray = ['C','C#','D','D#','E','F','F#','G','G#','A','A#','B']
    if @base != 12 then raise StandardError, "PCSet.notes only makes sense for mod 12 pcsets", caller end
    out_string = String.new
    transpose(-middle_c).pitches.each do |p|
      out_string += noteArray[p] + ", "
    end
    out_string.chop.chop
  end

  def info
    print "modulo: #{@base}\n"
    print "raw input: #{@input.inspect}\n"
    print "pitch set: #{@pitches.inspect}\n"
    print "notes: #{notes}\n"
    print "normal: #{normal_form.inspect}\n"
    print "prime: #{prime.inspect}\n"
    print "interval vector: #{interval_vector.inspect}\n"
    print "invariance vector: #{invariance_vector.inspect}\n"
    print "huron ADC: #{huron[0]}  pearsons: #{huron[1]}\n"
    print "balzano coherence: "
    if is_strictly_coherent?
      print "strictly coherent\n"
    elsif is_coherent?
      print "coherent\n"
    else
      print "false\n"
    end
  end


#  def lilypond
#  
#  end
#  
#  def musicXML
#    
#  end

###############################################################################
  private

  #
  # Convert every pitch array to a binary representation, e.g.:
  # [0,2,4,8,10] -> 010100010101
  #           2^n:  BA9876543210
  # The smallest binary number is the most left-compact.
  #
  def most_left_compact(pcset_array)
    if !pcset_array.all? {|pcs| pcs.length == pcset_array[0].length}
      raise ArgumentError, "PCSet.most_left_compact: All PCSets must be of same cardinality", caller
    end
    zeroed_pitch_arrays = pcset_array.map {|pcs| pcs.zero.pitches}
    binaries = zeroed_pitch_arrays.map {|array| array_to_binary(array)}
    winners = []
    binaries.each_with_index do |num, i|
      if num == binaries.min then winners.push(pcset_array[i]) end
    end
    winners.sort[0]
  end

end
```

I'm calling them as follows:

```
> my_pcset = PCSet.new([0,2,4,6,8,10])
> my_pcset2 = PCSet.new([1,5,9])
```

It shoud return:

```
> my_pcset = PCSet.new([0,2,4,6,8,10])
=> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
> my_pcset2 = PCSet.new([1,5,9])
=> [1, 5, 9]
```

But is returning nothing.
The code is available on [github](https://github.com/beausievers/Ruby-PCSet)
Thanks

Comment: where do you call `my_pcset = PCSet.new([0,2,4,6,8,10])` if it returns nothing? The code works just fine

Comment: Please, provide a [mre]. With a specific focus on the *minimal* part. I doubt it requires well over 300 lines of code to demonstrate your problem. In fact, I doubt it requires even 30 lines.

Comment: @user2535338 : If you set `my_pcset = PCSet.new(...)`, you set `my_pcset` to an instance of `PCSet`, and not to an instance of `Array`, as you indicated in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in terminal: `irb -r ./path_to_directory/pcset.rb` and then initialize the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation for the repo is bad as it does not explain how you should be running this.

The result of

```
my_pcset = PCSet.new([0,2,4,6,8,10])
```

should set my_pcset to an instance of a PCSet not an array, so these lines from the README file are confusing at best.

> ### 3. How to use it
>
> Make new PCSets:
>
> my_pcset = PCSet.new([0,2,4,6,8,10])
>
> => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>
> my_pcset2 = PCSet.new([1,5,9])
>
> => [1, 5, 9]

Looking at the code, I see `inspect` has been delegated to `@pitches`

```
  def inspect
    @pitches.inspect
  end
```

I think if you inspect my_pcset you will get the expected result.

```
my_pcset = PCSet.new([0,2,4,6,8,10])
p my_pcset # will print [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

or `my_pcset.inspect` will return what you are expecting.
```